# ListFragment backed by a Loader which fetches data from a server

Tags: android

I am currently implementing a ListFragment backed by a CursorLoader that reads a database table via a Provider.

I need it to..

- Have a last row in the list view that when the user clicks, loads more data to the database.
- The database data is fetched in a background process from the server (I am thinking of doing this in an extended CursorLoader.loadInBackground() implementation, then returning the Cursor once the data has populated the database.

Are there any good examples of this, or is there a framework/project which has worked on this problem?